# Google Earth Engine uploading table asset meets "invalid shapefile supporting file“

Tags: shapefile, google-maps, google-earth-engine, import

I am trying to upload a series of data coordinates to Google Earth Engine.

First, I used ArcGIS and converted the Excel data to shapefile and I got eight files.

However, when I am trying to upload them, a mistake came out like the first picture.

[image: Example_of_an_error_1]

> An invalid shapefile supporting file has been provided. The valid
>   extensions are: ".shx", ".dbf", ".cpg", ".fix", ".prj", ".qix",
>   ".sbn", ".shp.xml".

Then as the tip showed, I deleted the `.shp` file. But it did not work, either. The tip told me that `.shp` is demanded. What am I supposed to do?

[image: Example_of_an_error_2]

Answer (score 1):

`sbx` doesn't appear in that list of allowed shapefile components, but its in your list of uploaded source files. Read the error message carefully and you should spot this.

Minimally you should upload `.shp`, `.shx`, `.dbf` and `.prj` - the others might be useful but aren't always needed. `.cpg` is needed if your text has an unusual encoding. But anyway, don't upload `.sbx` if it tells you not to.

Comment: Thank you so much !!!!! It's my fault. I was so negligent and there will be no next time. A little question: sometimes the .shp.xml file  was not produced when trying to convert points data by arcgis, and would it be any difference?

Comment: I don't really know enough about ArcGIS but you could ask it as a question if you can't find an answer by searching.